# Detect if W3 Geolocation has already been allowed

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, ip-geolocation

I have a Google Map on my site and am using W3 Geolocation to detect a users location when they click a button, "Get current location". Then it should popup with the allow/deny infobar at the top of the browser window.

I don't want to prompt all my visitors for Geolocation access but do want to somehow remember if a user has already allowed the Geolocation and run Geolocation if so.

From my research this isn't possible but I'm hoping someone has ran into this situation before. The only way I can figure this can be done is setting a cookie.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no API call to know if user allow or disallow access to position. Only getCurrentPosition or watchPosition, which show prompt. So, setting cookies or storing user choice in some manner seems to be the only way.

Comment: Google Chrome won't ask the user again if he allowed detecting his location already once.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to write a comment.
the probleme occure only in google chrome since they remove it but not in other browsers.
the only solution i found is using cookies, but the probleme is that the user can go to browser setting and disable localization, but their is no way to know that, also the user could change the position and you would'nt know.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not exactly what you want, but I think it can be helpful.*

According to [W3C draft](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) you can try to get any cached value from browser (without user's confirmation) or fallback to custom method, if no cached value found.

Assuming user has agreed to provide geolocation, it will be cached. Example from the same W3C draft:

```
// Request a position. We only accept cached positions, no matter what 
// their age is. If the user agent does not have a cached position at
// all, it will immediately invoke the error callback.
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback,
                                         errorCallback,
                                         {maximumAge:Infinity, timeout:0});
```